# How many Perfect combinations are there for any number of directional symbols?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Imagine n is the number of symbols. Let's take n=3: ABC

There are 6 unique orderings of ABC:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

Easy. Let's take it up a notch.

Let's add arrows between these symbols, and let's stimulate that the a symbol cannot point back to itself. In that case, you have 8 possible configurations of arrows, as you can see here:

```
A->b, B->a, C->a
A->b, B->a, C->b
A->b, B->c, C->a
A->b, B->c, C->b
A->c, B->a, C->a
A->c, B->a, C->b
A->c, B->c, C->a
A->c, B->c, C->b
```

Some possible configurations converge on one symbol, like the first listed (B and C both point to A). Others, like the third, do not; the symbols in these configurations have one arrow in and one arrow out. Let's filter down to these configurations and call the resulting count P:

```
1. A -> B -> C (-> A)
2. A -> C -> B (-> A)
```

Now that kind of looks familiar from our permutations above because each of the permutations are one of these options at a different starting point:

```
1. A -> B -> C (-> A)
2. A <- B <- C (<- A)
ABC (1)
ACB (2)
BAC (2)
BCA (1)
CAB (1)
CBA (2)
```

**Okay, so finally here's my question: given n, how do I calculate P (in this case 2)?**

We can determine P for n=4 easily manually:

```
1. A -> B -> C -> D (-> A)
2. A -> B -> D -> C (-> A)
3. A -> C -> B -> D (-> A)
4. A -> C -> D -> B (-> A)
5. A -> D -> B -> C (-> A)
6. A -> D -> C -> B (-> A)
```

Notice 6 is the reverse of 1 like 2 is the reverse of 1 in the n=3.

Now, I like to call this subspace of all configurations the 'perfect' space because a 'perfect' hash function would be in this subspace, having no collisions, forming a loop. That's why I called the count of this space P.

So n=3 yields P=2, and n=4 yields P=6. How can I calculate P for any number?

Anyway, thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Seems to me that you want the number of $n-$cycles, which is just $P = (n-1)!$. Basically, determine what the next value maps to each time.

Comment: @CalvinLin you're right! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calvin Lin solved it:
$$P=(n−1)!$$  To see this, iteratively build the sequence "from left to right", keeping track of the number of choices available at each step.